# Mapping values of a dictionary to new dictionary with new keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I am reading table data from pdf files and then converting that table data into a dataframe and then into a dictionary. My problem is each time reading a table data keys of the dictionary are not fixed like it has some times keys like {'Sno':1,'ItemDescription':'ABC'} and sometimes it has {'Sl No':1,'Description':'XYZ'}. I wanted to create a new dictionary which has fixed keys like below where keys are the left side part and the right side part are the keys extracted from dataframe, so if it matches with in the list, values should map to the new keys.

```
Srno = ["Sno", "Sl No.", "Order No.", "PO No."]
Productdescription = ["Item Code / Product Description", "Description", "Description of Goods", "Particulars"]
HSNCode = ["HSN / SAC\nCode", "HSN Code", "HSN", "HSN/SAC"]
Quantity = ["Quantity"]
ASIN = ["ASIN"]
ISBN = ["ISBN/EAN/UPC"]
Rate = ["Unit Price\n[INR]", "Rate", "Unit cost", "List price"]
Tax = ["IGST[INR]\nAmount", "Tax rate", "Tax type", "Tax amount"]
Discount = ["Discount", "Disc. %"]
Total = ["Total amount", "Amount", "Total", "Total\n[INR]", "Line Total\n[INR]"]
Model = ["Model #"]
```

Here is the sample of dictionary which is created from the dataframe.

```
{'item': [{'Sno': 1,
   'ItemCodeProductDescription': 'TGMOCL0015CORSAIRMOUSE,M55RGBPRO,PART#CH-9308011-AP',
   'HSNSACCode': '8471.60.60',
   'Quantity': 7,
   'UnitPrice': 1741,
   'Total': 12187,
   'Rate': 18,
   'LineTotal': 14380.66},
  {'Sno': 2,
   'ItemCodeProductDescription': 'TGMOCL0013CORSAIRMOUSE,HARPOONPRO-BLK-RGB,PART#CH-9301111-AP',
   'HSNSACCode': '8471.60.60',
   'Quantity': 8,
   'UnitPrice': 1200,
   'Total': 9600,
   'Rate': 18,
   'LineTotal': 11328.0},
  {'Sno': 3,
   'ItemCodeProductDescription': 'TGCBCL0029CORSAIRCABINETSPEC-05,BLK-PART#CC-9011138-WW',
   'HSNSACCode': '8473.30.99',
   'Quantity': 37,
   'UnitPrice': 2225,
   'Total': 82325,
   'Rate': 18,
   'LineTotal': 97143.5},
  {'Sno': 4,
   'ItemCodeProductDescription': 'TGHSCL0003CORSAIRGAMINGHEADSETHS50StereoCarbonPART#CA-9011170-AP',
   'HSNSACCode': '8518.30.00',
   'Quantity': 92,
   'UnitPrice': 3000,
   'Total': 276000,
   'Rate': 18,
   'LineTotal': 325680.0},
  {'Sno': 5,
   'ItemCodeProductDescription': 'TGMOCL0001CORSAIRMOUSE,HARPOON-BLK-RGB,PART#CH-9301011-AP',
   'HSNSACCode': '8471.60.60',
   'Quantity': 43,
   'UnitPrice': 1018,
   'Total': 43774,
   'Rate': 18,
   'LineTotal': 51653.32},
  {'Sno': 6,
   'ItemCodeProductDescription': 'TGKBCL0001CORSAIRKEYBOARDK95PLTN-BLK-MXSpeed-RGBPART#CH-9127014-NA',
   'HSNSACCode': '8471.60.40',
   'Quantity': 8,
   'UnitPrice': 10750,
   'Total': 86000,
   'Rate': 18,
   'LineTotal': 101480.0},
  {'Sno': 7,
   'ItemCodeProductDescription': 'TGKBCL0007CORSAIRKEYBOARDK55-BLK-RBRDME-RGBPART#CH-9206015-NA',
   'HSNSACCode': '8471.60.40',
   'Quantity': 14,
   'UnitPrice': 2400,
   'Total': 33600,
   'Rate': 18,
   'LineTotal': 39648.0}]}
```

The final dictionary should be like this

```
{'item': [{'Srno': 1,
       'ProductDescription': 'TGMOCL0015CORSAIRMOUSE,M55RGBPRO,PART#CH-9308011-AP',
       'HSNCode': '8471.60.60',
       'Quantity': 7,
       'ASIN':Null 
       'ISBN':Null
       'Rate': 1741,
       'Discount':Null,
       'Model':Null,
       'Tax': 18,
       'Total': 14380.66}
```

Please suggest efficient way of creating a new dictionary from the old one.

Comment: What have you tried? You might start with a function `findKey(d, keys)` that iterates over a list of possible keys and returns the first found. Add that to a new dictionary with the canonical key. For efficiency, order the keys by ascending rarity.

Comment: I have tried to iterate over the keys of item and match with the ones in the list but it is returning me an empty list. Can you elaborate the method.?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since it is forbidden to change keys during the iteration in the original dictionary, it is only through the new dictionary here. And determining the correct key is possible through checking for entry into the list of possible options.

```
result_list = []

for i in items['item']:
    result = {}

    for key, value in i.items():
        if key in Srno:
            result['Srno'] = value
        elif key in Productdescription:
            result['ProductDescription'] = value
        elif key in HSNCode:
            result['HSNCode'] = value
        elif key in Quantity:
            result['Quantity'] = value
        elif key in ASIN:
            result['ASIN'] = value
        elif key in ISBN:
            result['ISBN'] = value
        elif key in Rate:
            result['Rate'] = value
        elif key in Tax:
            result['Tax'] = value
        elif key in Discount:
            result['Discount'] = value
        elif key in Total:
            result['Total'] = value
        elif key in Model:
            result['Model'] = value

    if result:
        result_list.append(result.copy())
```